# How to trim the XSLT use attribute expression

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am new to XSLT and I have got a special requirement. My XML file looks like below.

```
<results>
  <result>
    <Price>
      <LinePrices>
        <ProductId>ProductId:1000</ProductId>
        <Uom>KG</Uom>
        <Quantity>0</Quantity>
      </LinePrices>

      <LinePrices>
        <ProductId>ProductId:1002</ProductId>
        <Uom>EACH</Uom>
        <Quantity>0</Quantity>
      </LinePrices>
    </Price>
  </result>

  <result>
    <productlist>
      <productid>1000</productid>
      <relevance>0.9</relevance>
      <sponsored>0</sponsored>
    </productlist>
    <productlist>
      <productid>1001</productid>
      <relevance>0.8</relevance>
      <sponsored>0</sponsored>
    </productlist>
  </result>
</results>
```

I have to write XSLT keys to match the pattern. I have written the key for productlist as shown below.

```
<xsl:key name="productsIdForProduct" match="productlist" use="productid" />
```

In the similar way I am trying to write the key for LinePrices as shown below.

```
<xsl:key name="productsIdPrice" match="result/LinePrices" use="ProductId" />
```

However this returns 'ProductId:1000' in use attribute. I am trying to trim 'ProductId:' from the use attribute value. How can I write a trim expression to extract '1000' from 'ProductId:1000' inside XPATH expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use substring-after():

```
 substring-after(ProductId,':')
```